# Windows switching workspace on screen lock

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I've got 2 monitors with different resolutions. Every time I lock my system for longer durations, I find all the windows collected in the active workspace on the bigger screen. I never faced this issue when both my monitors had the same resolution. Would appreciate any help in fixing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this exact same problem and looks like an ongoing issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1295267

Some people are reporting success by disabling screen turn off and changing display connectors (if possible) - e.g. changing from DP/DVI/VGA etc.

Seems to have been an issue on and off for some time, so I'm not holding my breath for a fix :(

Comment: Disabling screen turn off worked for me. Thanks!